# Hiding MenuItem base on the Screen(Activity)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, menu, menuitem

Possible way of hiding menuItem base on the screen(Activity) is in the foreground. I have four (4) menuItem and I want to show two (2) in the action bar and force 2 into the overflow menu, in some  screen I want to show three (3) and have one (1) in the overflow menu,and in some screen the page tile is long I do not want it truncated but instead I want to show only  one (1) menuItem in the action bar and force the other three (3) into the overflow menu.

I need a generic way to do this.

I need to do this programmatically I don't need the xml answer of IfRoom, I have a BaseActivity which extends ActionBar and I have BaseActivityHelper where I have my menu layout inflated, all my other activity extends the BaseActivity.

**I would love to share my code but I'm not allowed to do so, the big question is if you are the one faced with this situation how will you do it.**

Answer (score 0):

The docs say:

> If you want to modify the options menu based on events that occur during the activity lifecycle, you can do so in the onPrepareOptionsMenu() method. This method passes you the Menu object as it currently exists so you can modify it, such as add, remove, or disable items. (Fragments also provide an onPrepareOptionsMenu() callback.)

So, you can grab your menu item in onPrepareOptionsMenu and call it's setShowAsAction(int actionEnum) with the appropriate option (SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS, SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM, or SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER)